Only calculate a numpy array at certain indexes given by a mask
Inside a large project I needed to process a 2D-numpy array in a certain way. Originally I implemented it using a quadruple-nested for-loop, with an if-test that checks if a condition is met for the given indexes. Nothing should happen if the if-test is False. Here is a minimal, reproducible example:
import numpy as np

L=8; K=20
data = np.random.randint(-10,10,(L,K)) + np.random.randint(-10,10,(L,K))*1j

check_pos = data > 0
check_neg_imag = np.imag(data) < 0

def for_looped(data,L,K,check_pos,check_neg_imag):
    processed = np.zeros((L,K,L,K), dtype=complex)
    for l in range(L):
        for k in range(K):
            for ll in range(L):
                for kk in range(K):
                    if (check_pos[l,k] and check_neg_imag[ll,kk]) or (check_neg_imag[l,k] and check_pos[ll,kk]):
                        processed[l,k,ll,kk] = data[l,k] * data[ll,kk].conj()
    return processed
processed = for_looped(data,L,K,check_pos,check_neg_imag)

This gets quite slow as the dimensions of the data increases, so I tried to vectorize the for-loops. However, I've had some trouble with the if-test. I tried just vectorizing without it:
def vectorized(data):
    return data[:,:,None,None] * data[None,None,:,:].conj()
processed_vec = vectorized(data)

This works, but it also wastes a lot of computing time on calculating values that are not used. I read one place that np.where() could be used in combination with a mask, e.g.:
mask = (check_pos[:,:,None,None] & check_neg_imag[None,None,:,:]) | (check_neg_imag[:,:,None,None] & check_pos[None,None,:,:])
def vectorized_where(data,mask):
    return np.where(mask, data[:,:,None,None] * data[None,None,:,:].conj(), 0)
processed_vec_where = vectorized_where(data,mask)

However, I checked the runtime using timeit and the code with np.where() is actually slower:
%timeit for_looped(data,L,K)
14.8 ms ± 44.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit vectorized(data)
45.5 µs ± 2.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit vectorized_where(data,mask)
65.9 µs ± 2.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

What I suspect is happening is that np.where() calculates data[:,:,None,None] * data[None,None,:,:].conj() for all the indexes, and then replaces the ones where the mask is True with 0. This also wastes computing time for what I'm using it for.
Is there a way to only calculate data[:,:,None,None] * data[None,None,:,:].conj() for the indexes given by the mask?

Yes python evaluates the arguments first and then passes whole arrays to where.  Many ufunc functions take a where parameter, which enables masked evaluation.  Use it with an out parameter.

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html

I tried multiply, but it seems to be even slower. I get: 99.3 µs ± 1.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

Given the sparsity of your mask, the 'unnecessary' calculations are not all that expensive.  The indexing need to bypass them, even in compiled code, consumes time.
